# problem in displaying span in HTML

Tags: html

I am creating nested spans as follows:

```
<span id="1">
   text1
   <span id="2"> text 2</span>
</span>
```

But somehow text 2 is being desplayed on new  line , may be it is styles sheet issue but i cant chnage style sheet due to some other resons.How can i overide default style sheet and make text 2 to be displayed on same line as text1

Comment: Please show the related CSS . By the way, you can't have entirely numeric IDs, it needs to start with a letter IIRC

Comment: @Pekka [You are correct](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter`

Answer (score 1):

`<span style="display:inline;">`

Comment: This **might** work, but there are other things that can trigger elements to cause line breaks than the display property.

Comment: than I suggest adding a class to all desired span elements and force a style reset.. css class can be defined in the header section if no access to stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

try `<span id="2" style="display:inline;">`

Answer (score 1):

If they are not displaying one next to the other, then some of your CSS is setting its `display: block`  (or similar) and not `display: inline`.

Easy fix - inspect the CSS setting it and remove, or explicitly state `display: inline` on that element.

Also, valid `id` (and `name` for that matter) attributes [must start with a [a-zA-Z]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the stylesheet has set spans to `display:block` which causes them to take their own line, such as the default styling for a `div`. To fix this you can add a style attribute:

```
<span id="1">
   text1
   <span id="2" style="display:inline"> text 2</span>
</span>
```

However, this may still be overridden by the stylesheet if it is using the `!important` flag.

For future debugging I recommend you look at tools like Web Inspector (Safari and Chrome), Firebug (Firefox) and Dragonfly (Opera). One final note, you can't have an id attribute that begins with a number, it must start with a letter.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following: [`display:inline`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp).